# Attach a disk to a running instance (in console)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I needed more space in my instance, so I tried attaching a disk to it. in the console i created a disk and attached it. But I don't see it on my instance when running:

```
df -h
```

I tried rebooting, and read the docs here: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attachdiskrunninginstance

I'm don't know what else to try...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try the following:

list disks:
`ls -l /dev/disk/by-path/`

see disk device usually `/dev/sdb` for second disk

`sudo mkdir /mnt/newdisk`

Note: The following command wil format and delete all data on new disk! Do not use if are mounting an already formatted disk containing data.

`sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount /dev/sdb /mnt/newdisk`

Regards
Paolo